# display days of the week javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display in a list the days of the week. For the current day I want to display the word Today. How can I do this with javascript?

```
<ul class="week-days">
    <li><a href="#"><span id="firstD">Today</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="secondD">Tue</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="thirdD">Wed</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="forthD">Thu</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="fifthD">Fri</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="sixthD">Sat</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="seventhD">Sun</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem you are trying to solve. You posted a question about JavaScript, but the only code you posted was markup. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C6LKS/1/

Comment: Thank you @Arun. Your answer was the best one, is working great.

Comment: looks like there is a bug.... because of operator precedence... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C6LKS/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding this at the bottom of your page (just above the body closing tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    $('.week-days li').each(function(){
      if ((new Date()).getDay() == i) {
        $(this).val('Today').html('Today'); 
      } 
      i++;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
// Find the unordered list element
var list = $('ul.week-days');

// Check what day it is today (0..6)
var today = (new Date()).getDay();

// Our day strings; in JS, "Sunday" is the beginning of the week
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

// Add a list item to the list, substituting "Today" if necessary
$.each(days, function(i, v) {
     list.append($('<li>' + (i == today ? 'Today' : v) + '</li>'));
});
```

Of course it's missing the `<a><span>...</span></a>` structure but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xqPJG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (only if you keep to the 3 letter abbr)

```
 var date = new Date().toString(); // Get the Date and return it as a string
 var day = date.split(' ')[0]; // Split the date and store the first index (day)
 $('.week-days li').each(function(){ // loop over the li 
    if($(this).html() === day){ // if this html is the same as day variable
      $(this).html('Today'); // change the html to 'Today'
    }
 });
```